# Js переменная из вне ?

Tags: ajax, javascript, переменные

Можно ли задать переменную вне js файла в которой она будет использоваться ?

нашел инфу что можно так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialogID = <php echo $dialog['id'] ?>;
    var userID = <php echo $users['id'] ?>;
</script>

<script src="/ajax/ajax.js"></script>
```

но не работает же, в консоле пишет

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Uncaught ReferenceError: dialogID is not defined
```

Comment: посмотрите что генерится, но

Comment: Странный нейминг. $users['id']. Точно не $user['id']?

Comment: у вас там ошибка из-за того что теги пхп неправильно написаны. Написано <php , а нужно <?php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте атрибут **data-*** какого-нибудь элемента в качестве хранилища данных. Для примера, возьмём статью.

```
<article data-uid="<?=$users['id'];?>" data-dialog="<?=$dialog['id'];?>">
Очень полезная статья...
</article>
```

Теперь, вы в любой момент можете получить доступ к данным:

```
var art = $('article');
console.log( art.data('uid') ); // id юзера 
console.log( art.data('dialog') ); // id диалога
```

Comment: Спасибо буду знать :)